# Get responsive html blocks with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need display 3 simple text html blocks in 3 columns such as the image, but I need a responsive behaviour

[image: 3 html blocks in 3 columns not responsive]

I need the behaviour will be responsive, running like this one...
Anybody could teach me the css code for this responsive behaviour?

[image: 3 html blocks in 3 columns responsive]

Thank you in advanced!

```
<p><strong>CARTELERA</strong></p> 
<table border="0"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td> <p>PELICULA1<br />Nombre1<br />Dirextor1<br />España</p> </td> 
      <td>PELICULA2<br />Nombre2<br />Dirextor2<br />España</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: use twitter bootstrap for this

Comment: @AnandJaju Why use such an heavy framework for few lines of pure CSS?

Comment: at least add ur html css .. fiddle .. so we can help u to improve..

Comment: @AnandJaju Bootstrap for something this basic.... Might as well have said use jQuery.

Comment: @Mr.Alien:he havent given any code so I just suggested him by thinking he is working on full responsive website..

Comment: I would start by not using a table. Split this into three <div> elements and float them each left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should post code here and we give you help with it. This site isn't a teaching resource.

That said, I will give you a point in the right direction. You could use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for this as it's a pre-built responsive framework.

If you want to have a go at doing it yourself, look at this code for a starting point.

```
<div id="container">
<ul class="section">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="section">
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the Css:

```
#container {
width: 100%;    
}

.section {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgU7w/)

Comment: Thank you @evilscary, your comment solve my problem!